# Merging binary variables in R to a new variable

Tags: r

I have three categorical variables i.e. stroke, MI and BP with values of 0 = yes and 1= No. I want to merge them to make a new variable "cvd" out of these three variables where each row with 0 gets 0 values in new cardiovascular variable. For example:

```
Stroke  MI  BP  CVD
0       1    1   0
1       1    1   1
1       1    0   0
```

I tried the following code but this is not what i want

```
transform(koratest, cvd=paste(stroke,MI, BP))
```

Can someone please help what could be the script for this?

Best,

Thank you for all the solutions. What to do if there is missing values in any of the values to be merged. I want missing values to be labelled as 1 but if there is 0 with missing value, i want cvd variable to have value of 1. For example:

```
 Stroke  MI  BP  CVD
0       1    1   0
1       NA   NA  1
0       NA   1   0
```

How could i achieve such output?

Answer (score 2):

Try,

```
(rowSums(df) == ncol(df)) * 1
#[1] 0 1 0
```

Comment: this looks good. Thank you. But my dataset has a list of other variables as well. How should i select only these three variable in the script and where should i define the name of new variable

Comment: If they are the first 3 on your data frame then `df[1:3]` or the index they are found on your df

Answer (score 1):

Another way:

```r
library(dplyr)

df <- data.frame(Stroke = c(0,1,1),
                   MI = c(1,1,1),
                   BP = c(1,1,0))

df %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(
    CVD = min(Stroke, MI, BP) 
  ) %>% 
  ungroup()

#> # A tibble: 3 × 4
#>   Stroke    MI    BP   CVD
#>    <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1      0     1     1     0
#> 2      1     1     1     1
#> 3      1     1     0     0
```

<sup>Created on 2022-07-11 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

Try this using `dplyr` `rowwise` function

```
library(dplyr)

df |> rowwise() |> mutate(CVD = if(all(c_across() == 1)) 1 else 0) |> ungroup()
```

- output

```
# A tibble: 3 × 4
# Rowwise: 
  Stroke    MI    BP   CVD
   <int> <int> <int> <dbl>
1      0     1     1     0
2      1     1     1     1
3      1     1     0     0
```

Comment: You may want to add a `ungroup`  to make it usual `tbl_df` object.

Answer (score 1):

Don't know how you arrange your variables. If they are separted vectors, this should work:

```
Stroke = c(0,1,1)
MI = c(1,1,1)
BP = c(1,1,0)
CVD = as.numeric(Stroke & MI & BP)
```

If a `data.frame`:

```
df$CVD = with(df, as.numeric(Stroke & MI & BP)
```

Or the solutions mentioned by others.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this:

```
library(tidyverse)

Data <- data.frame(Stroke = c(0,1,1),
                   MI = c(1,1,1),
                   BP = c(1,1,0))

Data <- Data %>% 
  mutate(CVD = if_else(Stroke == 1 &MI == 1 & BP == 1, 1, 0))
```

Answer (score 0):

`base R` option:

```
df$CVD <- apply(df,2, function(x) !any(0 %in% x)) + 0
df
```

Output:

```
  Stroke MI BP CVD
1      0  1  1   0
2      1  1  1   1
3      1  1  0   0
```

Comment: another aspect to this question: How i deal if i have any missing values in the variables to be merged. Detail has been edited in the question

Answer (score 0):

Using `rowSums` in `cbind` detects that `dat` is a data frame and creates such.

```
cbind(dat, CVD=+(rowSums(dat[c('Stroke', 'MI', 'BP')]) == 3))
#   Stroke MI BP CVD
# 1      0  1  1   0
# 2      1  1  1   1
# 3      1  1  0   0
```

If you only have these columns, it simplifies to:

```
cbind(dat, CVD=+(rowSums(dat) == 3))
```

---

*Data:*

```
dat <- structure(list(Stroke = c(0L, 1L, 1L), MI = c(1L, 1L, 1L), BP = c(1L, 
1L, 0L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to solves your problem:

```
df$CVD = with(df, pmin(Stroke, MI, BP)) 

  Stroke MI BP CVD
1      0  1  1   0
2      1  1  1   1
3      1  1  0   0

# or
library(data.table)

setDT(df)[, CVD := pmin(Stroke, MI, BP)]

# or
library(dplyr)

df = df %>% 
  mutate(CVD = pmin(Stroke, MI, BP))
```