# Removing missing values from merged categorical variables in R

Tags: r

In response to my previous question here:

[Merging binary variables in R to a new variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72937937/merging-binary-variables-in-r-to-a-new-variable)

I used the following code to merge categorical variables and it worked:

```
koratest<-koratest%>%
+     rowwise() %>%
+     mutate(
+         CVD = min(ptmi,ptschl,pthyact, ptap )
+     ) %>%
+     ungroup()
```

What to do if there is missing values in any of the values to be merged. I want missing values to be labelled as 1 but if there is 0 with missing value, i want cvd variable to have value of 1. For example:

```
 Stroke  MI  BP  CVD
 0       1    1   0
 1       NA   NA  1
 0       NA   1   0
```

How should i edit the above mentioned code in this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could first replace the NA with 1 and then `apply` the same function:

```
df[is.na(df)] <- 1
df$CVD <- apply(df,1, function(x) !any(0 %in% x)) + 0
df
```

Output:

```
  Stroke MI BP CVD
1      0  1  1   0
2      1  1  1   1
3      0  1  1   0
```

Answer (score 0):

`replace` them with `1`.

```
replace(dat, is.na(dat), 1) |> {\(.) transform(., CVD=+(rowSums(.) == 3))}()
#   Stroke MI BP CVD
# 1      0  1  1   0
# 2      1  1  1   1
# 3      0  1  1   0
```

---

*Data:*

```
dat <- structure(list(Stroke = c(0L, 1L, 0L), MI = c(1L, NA, NA), BP = c(1L, 
NA, 1L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))
```